# Developing on OSX through VNC, how to connect iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, vnc

I need to write my program through VNC on OSX and I need to test application on iPhone.

Is possible to connect iPhone via VNC  to be visible in xcode for testing?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to connect iPhone via VNC, make sure VPN-USB driver are install and then follow the steps given in apple [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/128-Managing_Devices/devices.html).

Things you will need:

- Your private key.
- your provisioning profile (with the UUID of your device added).
- Go to project settings and change code signing entity to your
  distribution profile.

then you can build and run after connecting your device through VNC.

You can follow [this](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices) blog to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have Windows PC, on which I'm connecting to OSX. Where I should install that USB driver ?
And the link to apple document isn't working.

Comment: I just noticed that you changed it to VPN driver. So screen would be shared through VNC and USB through VPN ? Am I right ?

Comment: VNC and VPN meaning is same, If you install VMWare, just google it to install driver for VMWare, it will give many links to install it.

Comment: This is a link-only answer and a good example of why those shouldn't be done- both links are dead.